# Register-ScheduledJob with Wait

Tags: powershell, wait

I use an ssh connection to a Windows server, and use the Register-ScheduledJob command.

The problem is that I want to add to the command a "Wait" function, and after that an "Unregister-ScheduledJob" command.

I tried a lot of research and find that I can use the "Wait-Job" command, but I can't do it.

Here is my PS command :

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name test-job -Trigger (New-JobTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddSeconds(3)) -ScriptBlock {echo "OK" >> C:\Users\test\Desktop\test-job.txt} ; Get-Job | Wait-Job | Get-ScheduledJob | Unregister-ScheduledJob -Force
```

The command is well executed, and I have the txt file, BUT my job is still in the list when I make a "Get-job" or "Get-ScheduledJob".

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `Get-Job` and `Wait-Job` doesn't work on Scheduled Jobs, so your last pipeline is essentially empty, and nothing happens.

Comment: But when I type "Get-Job', I have a result with my job name : test-job. So I think it's working, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how to do it, here is the code if it may help some people :

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MYPASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$account = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "MYDOMAIN\MYLOGIN"
$password; $opt = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddSeconds(5)
Register-ScheduledJob -Name SJOB-USER -Credential $account -ScheduledJobOption $opt -Trigger $trigger `
-ScriptBlock {Start-Job -Name JOB-USER `
-ScriptBlock {COMMAND1; COMMAND2} | Wait-Job; Start-Sleep -s 15; `
$encoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8; if (COMMAND-TEST) {Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer MY-SMTP-SERVER -Encoding $encoding -From "MAIL-SENDER" -To "MAIL-USER" -Subject "..." -Body "..." -BodyAsHtml}
else {Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer MY-SMTP-SERVER -Encoding $encoding -From "MAIL-SENDER" -To "MAIL-USER" -Subject "..." -Body "..." -BodyAsHtml}; `
Get-Job | Remove-Job -Force; Get-ScheduledJob | Unregister-ScheduledJob -Force}
```

What the code is doing :

- He is launching a background job with Exchange commands (that take time to be executed)
- So my ssh session can be disconnected immediately, without interrupting the execution of the commands
- Then it wait for the Exchange commands to be finished, and send me a mail to know if the commands had been well executed or not
- Once the mail is sent, it deletes all "Jobs" and "Scheduled-Jobs" in PowerShell